# How could one connect their iPhone to a Mac OS X's Safari Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, macos, safari, rack-pow

I'm using my local ip :

```
ipconfig getifaddr $(route -n get default|awk '/interface/ { print $2 }')
```

Which returns :

```
192.168.200.11
```

And I'm running a Sinatra app that can be accessed via my computer at :

```
http://localhost:3000
```

If I do on my iPhone :

```
192.168.200.11:3000
```

It times out. And the same results occur on my laptop as well when I try and connect to the same address.

How do I connect my iPhone from here so that I can see my locally running app?

**Extra miscellaneous infos**

From my Iphone if I go to :

```
192.168.200.11
```

It brings up my `pow is installed` page..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall issue on your computer.  It's allowing connections to port 3000 from localhost, but not from the local subnet.  However, that rule is different for port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You're sure your iPhone is on the same LAN as your computer? I.e. going to http://icanhazip.com/ on your iPhone gives you the same IP as going there with your computer?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily prove that they are om the same subnet.